# RANK() used in mysql and when I use a subquery to get rows of a particular rank the "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row" is thrown

Tags: mysql, sql, error-code

I want to arrange a table using rank function, partition it by one attribute and order it by another and then display rows of Rank 1.

The query:

```sql
SELECT *,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.id ORDER BY sales.time DESC ) as sales_row_num 
FROM sales 
WHERE ( SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.id ORDER BY sales.time DESC )
        FROM sales ) = 1 ;
```

> **Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row**

What do I do? How else can I frame my subquery as it is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.id ORDER BY sales.time DESC ) as sales_row_num 
    FROM sales 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE sales_row_num = 1 ;
```

Comment: How do I modify the query if I don't want sales_row_num to be displayed?

Comment: @JakkulaDivyaTej Simply replace an asterisk with separate columns list. Unneeded columns may be skipped too.